Is the expected value of a continuous random variable always defined if its support is bounded?
It is well known that there are random variables for which the expected value is undefined, e.g., if a random variable has a Cauchy distribution. However, the Cauchy random variable is supported on the whole of $\mathbb{R}$.
Is there any continuous random variable supported on a bounded interval where the expected value is undefined, or is it impossible to construct such a random variable if the support is bounded?
Happy if someone provides the argument here or points me at literature where this question is addressed. Thank you in advance.

If $X$ is a random variable with $P(|X|\leq c)=1$ for some constant $c\in\mathbb R$ then automatically $\mathbb E|X|\leq c<\infty$ so that $\mathbb EX$ is well-defined.

Thanks, @drhab, that corresponds with my intuition, but it is, strictly speaking, not an answer to the question.
